# C as "c" in all abbreviations or acronyms

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations, letters-of-the-alphabet

Does letter "c" read as [c] in all abbreviations or acronyms?

- BBC - company [k]
- PC - computer [k]
- RC - compiler [k]

Are there any abbreviations or acronyms where the letter C doesn't read as [c]?

Comment: Technically, those are acronyms. Abbreviations, e.g. "e.g." aren't meant to be spelled out. Although, I think abbreviations include acronyms, not everyone might agree.

Comment: @Hectorvon Alright, I've supplemented that to the question.

Comment: The only way "BBC" is an acronym is if you pronounce it "bubook" or similarly. SALT (Strategic Arms Limitation Treaty) is an acronym, because it is normally pronounced "salt" and *NOT* spelled aloud "s-a-l-t" in normal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about all acronyms, but in those mentioned and any that I know, **no**, the letter C is denoted by its name, that sounds like "see".